# The old log script was two days old and no longer worked

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, unix, amazon-ec2

After two days of the deleted script not working, I tried this method.

but the minutes-based deleted script is a properly working script.

The 5-minute script works, but the script does not work on days such as 4 or 7.

I tried this method. 2 days of deleted script

**find /home/path/file_name*  -mtime +2 -type f -delete**

but the minutes-based deleted script is a properly working script.

find /home/path/file_name*  -mmin +5 -type f -delete

The 5-minute script works, but the script does not work on days such as 4 or 7 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 4 days, use below

```
find /home/path/file_name* -mmin +5760 -type f -delete  #4*24*60
```

For 7 days, use below

```
find /home/path/file_name* -mmin +10080 -type f -delete  #7*24*60
```